# Как сделать инкремент 2х классов?

Tags: java

Уже искал на стаке подобные вопросы, но понятного ответа не нашел.
 Нужно чтобы класс Staff наследовал классы Pedagogical и Technical.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CalculateSalary {
public static void main(String args[]){
    File file=new File("staff.txt");
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Staff> staff=new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        in=new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String line=in.nextLine();
            String[] parts=line.split(" ");
                Staff sff=new Staff(parts[1], parts[2],Integer.parseInt(parts[3]),Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
                if(parts[0].equals("P")){
                    Pedagogical ped=new Pedagogical(Integer.parseInt(parts[6]),parts[5]);
                }
                else{
                    if(parts[6].equals("M")){
                        Technical tech=new Technical(true,parts[5]);
                    }
                    else{
                    Technical tec=new Technical(false,parts[5]);
                    }
                    /*dont works without {}*/
                }

        }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.print("NO FILE!");
    }
}
}
class Pedagogical{
int papers;
String degree;
public Pedagogical(int papers, String degree){
this.papers=papers;
this.degree=degree;
}
}
class Technical{
boolean managerial;
 String department;
 public Technical(boolean managerial, String department){
        this.managerial=managerial;
        this.department=department;
 }

}


 /*
Or Staff extends Technical and Pedagogical??
*/

class Staff {
    String Name, Surname;
     int birth_year, startedWork;
    public Staff(String Name, String Surname, int birth_year, int startedWork){
        this.Name=Name;
        this.Surname=Surname;
        this.birth_year=birth_year;
        this.startedWork=startedWork;
    }
   }
```

input:

P Bill Gates 1985 2011 MSc 3

T Steve Jobs 1989 2008 cleaning M

P Alan Turing 1995 2001 PhD 5
В самой задаче надо посчитать зарплату сотрудников, но это я смогу сделать.
Кроме этого надо запихать все это в аррейлист используя полиморфизм.
С этим то у меня проблема.

Comment: Множественного наследования в Java нет. А что пытаетесь таким образом добиться?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , после этого все элементы из всех классов должны были отправится в arraylist. Хотел добавлять только через один класс, добавив к нему остальные..

Comment: Опишите что у вас не получается. Лучше с примером кода. Может вам наследование и не нужно

Comment: @ArchDemon, Поправил вопрос

Comment: Сделайте наоборот класс Staff общим, от него наследуйте Technical и Pedagogical.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IEntry {
    // можно сюда добавить общий метод
}

class Pedagogical implements IEntry {
    ...
}

class Technical implements IEntry {
    ...
}

class Staff implements IEntry {
    ...
}

List<IEntry> array = new ArrayList<>();
```